# Can I get an explanation of HDCP's key exchange protocol?

Tags: key-exchange

I'm talking about HDCP v1.x. The specification is a too dense for me and easy-to-understand information about it on the net is scarce.

What I've gathered is:

- that there is a master key that is a 40-by-40 matrix of 56-bit values.
- each device that is part of the HDCP ecosystem has a unique array of 40 secret keys generated such that a shared value can be calculated from two different arrays and selection vectors.

How does the key exchange work and why does it work? How is the master key related to each device's unique array of secret keys?